# Splunk - How to schedule search every 15 minutes?

Tags: search, triggers, alert, splunk

My current configuration is like this[image]

i need to run search every 15 minutes and trigger an alert to send email, the problem is that even i can see it in log sometimes alert is not triggered, can anybody help with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities I'm thinking here which clients keep bumping into,

P1: You're suffering from concurrent searches overload in which your scheduled searches skip runs because too many of them are running in parallel
Fix: Ensure your searches are optimised, move them away from minute 0 and spread them randomly over the hour, for instance

```
4-59/15 * * * *
8-59/15 * * * *
```

P2: What you call an alert, really isn't an alert and rather than searching for keywords and processing the output into aggregated metrics you're forwarding the entire output, sometimes over 15MB, clogging your Exchange Server
Fix: An alert should use a reporting command (stats, chart) which you can marry up with Eval statements to set thresholds and fire an alert when the conditions you're after are met
This still generates a URL on the email so the interested team can login to Splunk to check the raw events behind it